# The background image in my react application is not showing

Tags: css, reactjs

The background image in my react application is not showing!

I've applied it to the index.html file in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>React and Webpack4</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: url("background.png");
      background-size: cover;    
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;   /* For flexibility */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="index"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/background.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Dont seem like React issue. Rather your server issue maybe. Hit http://localhost:8080/background.png in new tab and keep modifying path until you can figure out where's it being served from.

Comment: where is your `background.png` image stored ?

Comment: it's in the root, on the same level as the index.html file

Comment: I get this explaination...'because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback'

Comment: If you used create-react-app to create the initial app, that file should live up in /public/ directory if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't do this, so is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Where is your react app.js?